# How to format my pendrive?ade it bootable by power iso

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-mint, linux-distributions

I made my pendrive bootable by poweriso and loaded centos on it. But now my pendrive cant be formatted. First it was showing the in this pc but when i tried to format it there was an error and now i cant see it in this pc .It is visible in device manager showing read only mode.

Comment: You mention Device Manager, is this Windows?  Or Linux?  For Windows, you could use Rufus - http://rufus.akeo.ie/ and I have had good luck with it.  I know there are USB Tools in LINUX Mint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]**Warning doing the operation on the wrong disk will cause you more issues**

In windows the most reliable way is to use the `CMD` prompt and run `diskpart`

- Enter `list disk` make a note of which is the USB disk - you can usually tell easily by the reported capacity.
- Then issue `select disk N` - replace N with the drive number from before
- Then run `clean` - this should then make the disk acceptable to any system for formatting.

On linux you can accomplish the same thing by running:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdN bs=1024K count=1`

Where `n` would be a, b, c..